# I have a SOT23 electronic part AEWU9 - where can I find a datasheet?

Tags: surface-mount, sot23

I have a SOT-23 part with part number AEWU9 but couldn't find any datasheet on the net. Where can I search more for this part?

Comment: Where did you get the part from? The supplier usually have datasheets for their sold components.

Comment: If it's not in its original packaging, how can you ensure that it has not become damaged by static electricity?

Comment: Take a guess that U9 might be a date code, and google SOT23 AEW. Second hit: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6469-MAX6484.pdf. Search that document for AEW.